# Особенности работы ОС при операциях ввода вывода процесса

Tags: процесс, ос, процессор

Говорят, что процесс уступает процессор другому процессу, когда нужно выполнить операцию ввода вывода. Не могу осознать, почему нужно уступать процессор другому процессу, если мне нужно ВЫПОЛНИТЬ операцию ввода вывода (например запрос в БД или запись в файл), а не просто поставить на процессор какой то другой процесс. Кто собственно тогда будет выполнять эту ИО операцию тогда?
Если ИО это запрос в сеть, то тут еще более менее понятно и логично, ведь этот запрос будет выполняться на другой машине.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Весь ввод-вывод выполняет ядро ОС. Если невозможно немедленно получить данные (например из дискового кеша) то ядро ОС останавливает текущий процесс (если он не указал, что операция асинхронна). И процессу не вернут управление, пока данные не появятся.

Обратите внимание, что процессор самостоятельно может получить данные только из оперативной памяти. Если надо получить данные с жесткого диска или любого другого устройства ввода вывода, которые работают значительно медленнее оперативной памяти происходит следующее: 1. Процессор отдает команды на контроллер прямого доступа к памяти (DMA) сообщая ему "сейчас жесткий диск будет отдавать тебе данные по каналу номер такому то, положи их в память по адресу такому то". 2. Процессор отдает команду контроллеру жесткого диска "прочитай такие то данные в канал DMA такой то". На этом работа процессора над получением данных пока окончена. Данные будут получаться очень долго с точки зрения процессора. Жесткий диск сам прочитает данные, а контроллер DMA сам положит их в память, это будет происходить без использования процессора. Когда данные будут готовы контроллер диска вызовет прерывание, которое обработает процессор, ядро ОС скопирует данные в память запросившего процесса и разбудит этот процесс.

Все это время, пока данные готовятся без участия процессора, будь они на устройстве ввода-вывода даннго компьютера или где то в сети, процессору заняться в общем то нечем. Поэтому право пользования процессором будет передано тому процессу, которому это сейчас требуется.